# How do I accurately time how long it takes to call a function on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, benchmarking

I would like to know how long it's taking to send a message to an object with at least a 1ms accuracy.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `mach_absolute_time` to measure in nanoseconds.

```
#import <mach/mach_time.h>

uint64_t startTime = 0;
uint64_t endTime = 0;
uint64_t elapsedTime = 0;
uint64_t elapsedTimeNano = 0;

mach_timebase_info_data_t timeBaseInfo;
mach_timebase_info(&timeBaseInfo);

startTime = mach_absolute_time();

//do something here

endTime = mach_absolute_time();

elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
elapsedTimeNano = elapsedTime * timeBaseInfo.numer / timeBaseInfo.denom;
```

Reference:
[Technical Q&A QA1398: Mach Absolute Time Units](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2004/qa1398.html)

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I do:

```
NSDate * start = [NSDate date];
// do whatever I need to time
NSLog(@"time took: %f", -[start timeIntervalSinceNow]);
```

The output will be in seconds (with a decimal portion).  `NSDate`s have resolution on the scale of milliseconds, although I'm not sure precisely how accurate they are.

If the code you're trying to time is too fast, put it in a loop that runs the code a hundred times.  (That assumes, of course, that the code you're timing has no side effects.)

Comment: This is what I run. I personally don't care if it is too fast since I only care about bottlenecks. =)

Answer (score 0):

Use **dispatch_benchmark** to log method execution time in nanoseconds.
It has a much nicer syntax than manually looping and calling **mach_absolute_time()** dispatch_benchmark is part of Grand Central Dispatch. This function is not publicly declared, so you’ll have to do that yourself before use :

`extern uint64_t dispatch_benchmark(size_t count, void (^block)(void));`

I am using this for log execution time :

```
size_t const  blockIterations = 1; //block call count
uint64_t t = dispatch_benchmark(blockIterations, ^{ //your code inside block
        [self TEST_processJSONDataRecordsWithCompletionHandler:^(id handler) {}];
    });
NSLog(@" Avg. Runtime in nanoseconds : %llu ns", t);
```

Credit goes to [Benchmarking](http://nshipster.com/benchmarking/)

Comment: If it's not public, is it still possible to have `dispatch_benchmark` in Swift?

Comment: @Cœur yes, possible, see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946864/how-to-call-dispatch-benchmark-from-swift