# How can I measure the time it takes to perform a method?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How can I measure the time it takes to perform a method call? I would like to know in order to time my delays properly. I'd appreciate any help you guys could give me.

```
//Start measuring here
[self method];
//Stop measuring here
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I accurately time how long it takes to call a function on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646815/how-do-i-accurately-time-how-long-it-takes-to-call-a-function-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score -1):

Use what's called a profiler. I don't know of any for the iPhone, but there's most likely at least one out there. Google for "iphone profiler" or something like that.