# How to call dispatch_benchmark from Swift

Tags: c, swift, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

`dispatch_benchmark()` is a function in `GCD` that isn't exported. However, you may call it in `Objective C` by declaring it in your code:

```
uint64_t dispatch_benchmark(size_t count, void (^block)(void));
```

How can I do this is `Swift`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put the declaration into your bridging header:

```
@import Foundation;

uint64_t dispatch_benchmark(size_t count, void (^block)(void));
```

That will make the function automatically available in Swift.

Comment: Wow, what a trick, didn't know I can import not only frameworks and headers but function declaration as well. Thank you! @Sulthan

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Technically you are not importing. The header just tells the compiler that such a function is present somewhere. The linker will do the rest.

Comment: got it, good to know.